# How do I make text input box bigger with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've been learning web development for about a month now and I recently got stuck on something. I was making a simple login page as practice but when I try to make the input fields bigger, it doesn't do anything. This is my HTML and CSS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en_US">
    <head>
        <!-- Meta Tags -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Isaac Guillen">  
    
        <!-- Link CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/style.css">
    
        <!-- Website Title -->  
        <title>My Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="Login-Box">
            <h1 class="login-txt">Login</h1>
            <div class="usrname-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username">    
            </div>
            <div class="passwd-input">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="submit-button">
                <input type="button" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Fira Code";
}

.login-txt{
    font-size: 60px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1400px;
    top: 150px;
}

.usrname-txt{
    font-size: 40pt;
}
```

Can anyone help me? I don't know if I did anything wrong.

Comment: how do u expect that...you have not added the class related to the input tag in the CSS file.

Comment: What have you tried to actually make the inputs bigger? You can increase their width and height using `input { width: 200px; height: 50px; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you changed only the size of a different element not a textarea.
You can correct it by adding a class to both textareas and than changing their width and height.

Just like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en_US">
    <head>
        <!-- Meta Tags -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Isaac Guillen">  
    
        <!-- Link CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/style.css">
    
        <!-- Website Title -->  
        <title>My Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="Login-Box">
            <h1 class="login-txt">Login</h1>
            <div class="usrname-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="username-area">    
            </div>
            <div class="passwd-input">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="password-area">
            </div>
            <div class="submit-button">
                <input type="button" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Plus CSS:

```html
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Fira Code";
}

.login-txt{
    font-size: 60px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1400px;
    top: 150px;
}

.usrname-txt{
    font-size: 40pt;
}

.username-area{
  width: 30%;
  height: 40px;
}

.password-area{
  width: 30%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong class selector, try this css:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Fira Code";
}
input{
  font-size: inherit; /*Takes parent element's font size*/
}

.login-txt{
    font-size: 60px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1400px;
    top: 150px;
}

.usrname-input{ /*usrname-txt does not exists*/
    font-size: 40pt;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pjm5b4d0/2/

Answer (score -1):

You have to select the input fields using a class or an id.

Here is a quick example:

```css
input {
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
```